# Getting Error when i trigger the script from TFS when the browser type is IE

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, tfs

We are doing the Continuous integration using C# selenium for web base application. We have trigger the script from TFS using the test agent. But the build or the execution is getting successful if the browser type is chrome. For the IE bower we are facing the issue. Please help us in resolving this issue.

Note: When we trigger manual execution from server , execution in IE happens successfully.

Below is my Exception screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQX4e.png)

Comment: you have timeout exception, did you tried to browse with the port that in the exception

Comment: @Devavrat Hegde Which version of IE do you use? Just try to use the latest IE, then check it again. The new IE driver has fixed some of those

Answer (score 0):

Seems it related to the Webdriver.

Just try below things to check if that works for you:

1 .Try the latest IE

2 .Include setting capabilities of the browser when starting it. Try the below settings and see if it works to help it stay focused on the newly opened window.

```
capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
capabilities.setCapability("ie.ensureCleanSession", true);
webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

3 .Edit the browser profile and increase timeout to 180 seconds or more from default 60 seconds. Please note that this constructor is available in .Net API only.

For internet explorer driver, you can use below syntax.

```
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"z:\seleniumc", new InternetExplorerOptions(),TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

Refer to [Selenium Webdriver](http://selenium-interview-questions.blogspot.sg/2015/05/http-request-to-remote-webdriver-server.html) for details.